# Repeated prompt for option while running SCP script

Tags: cmd, file-transfer, scp

When I run an SCP script

```
scp -W Scp\password.txt -P 22 server:/file_location
scp -W Scp\password.txt -P 22 server:/file_location
```

in command prompt I get the following prompt:

```
Do you want to trust this new host key and continue connecting?
Please type 'no','once', or 'always':
```

As I attempt to type first letter of any option above, it keeps on repeating and prompts the same thing.

```
Please type 'no','once', or 'always':
Please type 'no','once', or 'always':
Please type 'no','once', or 'always':
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You say you're running a script? Please edit your question to include the script. Do you know what specific program is being invoked to perform the SCP operation?

Comment: I am not sure how my writing the script changes/helps the problem. Nevertheless, I have added the script too.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help writing software. If you're just having trouble running someone else's program, it's not really on topic here.

Comment: Where is that `scp` program from? The OpenSSH `scp` utility doesn't have a `-W` option.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found that it is resolved by copying and pasting the word you are trying to type in. For me I copied the work always and pasted it into cmd.

Comment: How the heck did you EVER figure that out?  This post saved me so much trouble.  But really, how did you figure that out?